# How to get previous element by event target?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, element

I am trying to get the previous `div/ class/ wrapper/ container` by `event.target` in React javascript. Its a table and here's the `DOM` tree. When I click the cell with "1", the event.target will output

```
<div class="id">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
```

How can I make it output `<div class="Table row">` instead? Thanks

Table:

```
id name location
1  test test      #the below html dom is for this row
```

DOM:

```
<div class="Table row" custom_att="test">
  <div class="id">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
onMouseDownEvent(e){
    var ele = e.target;
    //do something with ele
}
```

Comment: Is this about Python? Where is your code?

Comment: @mzjn updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.target demo</title>
  <style>
  span, strong, p {
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="Table row">
  <div class="id">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
 <div id="log">
   
 </div>
<script>
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
 
  $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.target.parentNode.nodeName );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Comment: Thanks your answer, how about if I want to get the text inside <div>, <div class="Table row" custom_att="test">

Comment: You can use innerHTMl